# Honeywell T6360 wiring - follow installation wiring guide positions or numbers?

Tags: wiring, thermostat

The following picture shows a Honeywell T6360 Room Thermostat wiring connections.  You will note they are numbered in the order **2 3 4 1 5 6**.
[image]

The Installation Instructions that accompany this unit, contains the wiring diagram below.  In this diagram, the connections are numbered in the order **1 2 3 4**.  This is very confusing and I'm not sure if I should copy the positioning from the installation guide or connect to the marked numbers (even though they are out of position).

What is the correct way to proceed?

[image]

<sub>Click for full size image</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Use the numbers.

The position of the terminals in the wiring diagram is likely just for ease of drawing, and may not exactly model the actual device.

Comment: Wired and working thanks.  Additional tip.  There was a more accurate wiring diagram (positionally correct) on  a sticker stuck on the back of the stat faceplate.

Answer (score 1):

I just connected according to the numbers, image below. Live on 1: red. Neutral on 2: blue. Switched live on 3: yellow. Note that your cable colours may be different.

[image: termostat cabling]

Answer (score 0):

1. connect the heater cables at terminals 3 and 2.
2. then check the power from socket with tester and connect that one with terminal 1.
3. the other one is neutral and should be connected at terminal 2.